# Can administration menu be configured with a stripped down menu that only gives the user access to post content?

Tags: 6, users

How would I go about setting up stripped down administration menu so that non-privileged users can see a menu allowing them to post content that they have permissions for?  Right now the user sees no menus in their admin menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the role permission settings you can do so allowing him for `access administration menu` and then checking required permission sets (e.g. `access administration pages`)

Comment: How can I remove the extra links that show up where the user doesn't have permission such as site building, site configuration, user management?

Comment: See the permission page under system module and user module.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because that gives me a menu that allows the user to add content, but I checked the system module and user module permissions and the user doesn't have access to any of them, but the links still appear in admin menu for that user.

Comment: Can you list those links which are visible and still redirect to 'page not found'?